# How can I repeat top module code N times verilog code ? (Synthesis Way)

Tags: for-loop, verilog, synthesis

If we have a top module that connect all instances from the codes together , So if we try to repeat (reiterate) the whole code which is the top module many times, How we can do this in synthesis way without using for-loop ??
Example to illustrate that :

```
for(i=0;i<13;i++){

module(1)
module(2)
module(3)
module(4)
module(N)}
```

I already connect modules from 1 to N in one module (Top module),but the question now ,how can I repeat it 12 times ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a much more detailed example of what you are trying to do? And explain why you do not want to use a `generate-for` loop.

Comment: for(i=1;i<13;i++){
module1
module2
module3
module4}
I have already withe the codes (1-4) through the top module..Now how can i repeate them 12 times ??
Thanks in advance ! @dave_59

Comment: I want to repeat N modules 12 times using verilog code..but I think that for.loop it is not synthesis ..isn't it ? So what is the optimum way to do that ? @dave_59

Answer (score 1):

for-loops are synthesizable so log as they can static unroll.

```
module top(/*...*/);
// nets

genvar idx_g;
generate
  for(idx_g=0; idx_g<12; idx_g=idx_g+1) begin : looplabel
    moduledef1 inst1(.*);
    moduledef2 inst2(.*);
    // ...
    moduledefN instN(.*);
  end : looplabel
endgenerate
endmodule
```